# Access denied to database for user when connecting to mysql from vbscript

Tags: mysql, vbscript, odbc

I have this code in a vbscript...

```
ConString = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=192.168.0.5;" &_
  "Database=EWS;User=EWSimportUser;Password=xxxxxxx;Option=3;"

set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection"): conn.open ConString
```

My script fails at the set conn line with the following error message...

> Error:    [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver]Access denied for user 'EWSimportUser'@'192.168.0.%' to database 'EWS'

I know this user has the correct privileges to this database because I can connect to the db using mysql workbench on the same server.

I also tried using an administrative mysql user with all rights granted and I also get an access denied message for this user.

Can anyone suggest something I might be doing wrong or any steps I might have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the database name is case sensitive.  I changed 'EWS' to 'ews' and it worked.

(I'm so used to case-insensitivity being ok with sql that I assumed it would not be a problem)